# Anaconda package conflicts

Tags: python, anaconda

I swear issues like this have plagued Anaconda for years.  I started totally fresh today on a Windows 11 machine, uninstalled AC, installed the most recent thing you get when you go to their homepage and click download (=2022.05).  Then, if you start Spyder, it tells you a new version is available.  It is smart enough to know you installed Spyder by Anaconda, so it tells you exactly what to do: "conda update anaconda" then"conda install spyder=5.3.3.".  I do this.  Or did, 20 minutes ago.  "conda update anaconda" is the *only* things I've done since the install that could have affected AC.  That went fine, now "conda install spyder=5.3.3"  And, of course solving for the environment fails, has all these issues, conda is right now scouring all my installed packages to find conflicts.

Maybe I should be brave and just post this as a bug to AC.  Or find another python packager.  But, when AC works it is *great*.  Ugh.